# Making a simpler parser function for a wiki

Tags: parsing, wiki, mediawiki-templates

I need a template on a wiki about a game ([Alphabetty Wiki](https://alphabettysaga.fandom.com/fr/)) that gives a range of levels when given a particular level (e.g. "42" -> "1-50")

I could make one using many #ifexpr, but I am wondering now if there is a simpler solution.
I tried with #switch but it seems bulkier.

I am asking this just to learn a bit more about parser functions, as the template I made already kinda works.

Template:

```
{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=50|1-50|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=95|51-95|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=140|96-140|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=185|141-185|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=230|186-230|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=275|231-275|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=320|276-320|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=365|321-365|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=410|366-410|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=455|411-455|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=500|456-500|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=545|501-545|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=590|546-590|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=620|591-620|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=650|621-650|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=680|651-680|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=710|681-710|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=740|711-740|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=770|741-770|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=800|771-800|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=830|801-830|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=860|831-860|<!--
-->{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=890|861-890|891-920}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

You can make tests directly on the wiki if you know a bit how wikicode works (you don't need an account to make edits, switch to "Source editor"): https://alphabettysaga.fandom.com/fr/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le:Chapitre?action=edit

Thank you for your time.

Comment: depends on which extensions you have in the wiki, array and loop extensions may be the solution

Comment: I'm just asking for the basic Extension:ParserFunctions : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions

Comment: Y'a Scribunto sur le wiki, tu peux faire un script lua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some arithmetics with `{{{#expr:}}`:

```
<includeonly>{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=50|1-50|{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}}<=590|<!--

range length is 45

-->{{#expr: 51 + trunc ( ( {{{1|}}} - 50 ) / 45 ) * 45 }}-{{#expr: 95 + trunc ( ( {{{1|}}} - 50 ) / 45 ) * 45 }}|{{#ifexpr:{{{1|}}} <= 890|<!--

range length is 30

-->{{#expr: 591 + trunc ( ( {{{1|}}} - 590 ) / 30 ) * 30 }}-{{#expr: 620 + trunc ( ( {{{1|}}} - 590 ) / 30 ) * 30 }}|

891-920
}} }} }}</includeonly><noinclude>
{| class="wikitable"
! Level !! Range
|-
| 5 || {{Range|5}}
|-
| 45 || {{Range|45}}
|-
| 55 || {{Range|55}}
|-
| 100 || {{Range|100}}
|-
| 585 || {{Range|585}}
|-
| 595 || {{Range|595}}
|-
| 885 || {{Range|885}}
|-
| 895 || {{Range|895}}
|}</noinclude>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Mashin, this is much more elegant than my nested list.
Furthermore, I wonder if there is a nesting limit for #ifexpr, even if my first try seems to work for bigger numbers.

Comment: There is indeed a [depth limit](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Expansion_depth), defaults to 40 levels including any nesting of templates and parser functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the huge nesting (which, beside not looking that good, is also [limited](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Expansion_depth)) by using a `#switch` but with reversed logic.

Instead of comparing `{{{1|}}}` to values (which wouldn't work for ranges), compare the boolean value "true" to logical expressions using `#expr`. In practice, the function `#expr` represents "true" by "1" so you would actually compare `1`:

```
{{#switch:1
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=50}} = 1-50
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=95}} = 51-95
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=140}} = 96-140
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=185}} = 141-185
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=230}} = 186-230
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=275}} = 231-275
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=320}} = 276-320
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=365}} = 321-365
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=410}} = 366-410
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=455}} = 411-455
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=500}} = 456-500
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=545}} = 501-545
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=590}} = 546-590
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=620}} = 591-620
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=650}} = 621-650
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=680}} = 651-680
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=710}} = 681-710
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=740}} = 711-740
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=770}} = 741-770
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=800}} = 771-800
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=830}} = 801-830
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=860}} = 831-860
| {{#expr:{{{1|}}}<=890}} = 861-890
| #default = 891-920
}}
```